# Mapping one matrix to another matrix position

Tags: r, matrix

I will do my best to explain this. I have a data set, out of which I create a matix from one column and do a tcrossprod on it, simplified example data set is...

```
key value
a1  1000
a2  500
a3  1500
a5  200
```

My problem arises as I have another matrix that I want to scale the original matrix with which I have calculated separately, simplified example would be...

```
    a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
a1  1   5   10  15  50
a2  5   1   20  25  75
a3  10  20  1   30  80
a4  15  25  30  1   100
a5  50  75  80  100 1
```

I am looking to map the second matrix to the first but I can't figure out a way to do it, I am looking to end up with two matrices that I can multiply together, e.g., the first matrix is the result of the trcrossprod the second matrix is calculated separately.

The two matrix do not have the same dimensions which is why I am looking to map the corresponding values of the second matrix into the same dimensions as the first so I have a simple scalar matrix calculation.

```
    v1      v2      v3      v4          a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
1,  1000000 500000  1500000 200000      a1  1   5   10  50
2,  500000  250000  750000  100000      a2  5   1   20  75
3,  1500000 750000  2250000 300000      a3  10  20  1   80
4,  200000  100000  300000  40000       a5  50  75  80  1
```

So the keys of the first matrix need to map to the second in the correct position so I can do a simple scaling of matrix_1 * matrix_2.

I would then get a new matrix that looks like this...

```
    v1       v2       v3        v4
1,  1000000  2500000  15000000  10000000
2,  2500000  250000   15000000  7500000
3,  15000000 15000000 2250000   24000000
4,  10000000 7500000  24000000  40000
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to subset the second matrix to remove the fourth row and column?

Comment: Yes, I need to subset the second matrix to match the dimensions of the first but the second matrix has no real rule as to which I can remove, it is based on a key I have in the first matrix so hence I need to map the second's attributes to the first.

Comment: `m2[rownames(m2) %in% m1[, "key"], colnames(m2) %in% m1[, "key"]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Reproduce data
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "key value
a1  1000
a2  500
a3  1500
a5  200")
v1 <- as.matrix(df1[, 2, drop = FALSE])
rownames(v1) <- df1[[1]]
m1 <- v1 %*% t(v1)

#         a1     a2      a3    a5
# a1 1000000 500000 1500000 2e+05
# a2  500000 250000  750000 1e+05
# a3 1500000 750000 2250000 3e+05
# a5  200000 100000  300000 4e+04

m2 <- as.matrix(read.table(header = TRUE, text = "    a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
a1  1   5   10  15  50
a2  5   1   20  25  75
a3  10  20  1   30  80
a4  15  25  30  1   100
a5  50  75  80  100 1"))


m1 * do.call("[", c(list(m2), dimnames(m1)))

#         a1      a2       a3      a5
# a1 1.0e+06 2.5e+06 15000000 1.0e+07
# a2 2.5e+06 2.5e+05 15000000 7.5e+06
# a3 1.5e+07 1.5e+07  2250000 2.4e+07
# a5 1.0e+07 7.5e+06 24000000 4.0e+04
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I need to test this solution on the proper data but this looks very promising!

Comment: I am getting a matric of na when I apply the code to my matrices...when I look at the data seperately I don't see a problem but the 'mapping' of the list to the dims seems to not be happening correctly...I have a concatonated key that has a space...might that cause the issues?       key_1 0.25 key_1 0.5 key_1 1 key_1 10 key_1 15 key_1 2 key_1 20 key_1 3 key_1 30 key_1 5 key_2 0.25 key_2 0.5 key_2 1
NA      NA  NA  NA   NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA  NA
NA.1    NA  NA  NA   NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA  NA
NA.2    NA  NA  NA   NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA  NA

Comment: It _might_ be the problem indeed. Base R does not like spaces in names, it might have applied `make.names()` implicitely somewhere. Possible quick fix: try to `gsub(" ", "", key)` everywhere

Comment: Thanks. I removed the space but same issue. Very strange as your example works perfectly but not with my data.

Comment: Update, I worked out an alternative method for the moment, I used melt on the two matrix and joined.

Comment: Look at dimnames(m1)  and dimnames (m2)

Comment: Sorry for delay in getting back...the dimames are different between m1 and m2...m1 is this [[1]]
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30" "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "37" "38" "39"...the [[2]] set looks okay as in they have the same 'mapping' keys though their 'ordering' is different.

Comment: `Map(intersect, dimnames(m1), dimnames(m2))`?